Having trouble with testing program that uses scanner for user input in java
I am trying to test one method from a program.
Method:
        private static int dateValidation(Scanner sc)
    {
        int date;

        do
        {
            
            System.out.println("Please enter date of birth in numbers:");
            date = sc.nextInt();
                        sc.nextLine();

            if (date < 1 || date > 31)
            {
                System.out.println("Error. Please enter an appropriate date between 1-31 inclusive.");
            }
            
        } while (date < 1 || date > 31);

        return date;
    }

And I am testing stimulated user input by doing this:
import java.io.*;

public class programTest
{
        public static void dateValidationTest()
        {
                String inputTest = "10";
                System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputTest.getBytes()));
                assertEquals(10, program.dateValidation());

        }

}


Which gives me this error as dateValidation requires Scanner as input
programTest.java:11: error: method dateValidation in class program cannot be applied to given types;
        assertEquals(10, program.dateValidation());
                                          ^
  required: Scanner
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error


However when I add inputTest into it like assertEquals(10, program.dateValidation(inputTest)), another error occurs:
programTest.java:11: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Scanner
        assertEquals(10, program.dateValidation(inputTest));
                                                          ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error


And also tried this: assertEquals(10, program.dateValidation(System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputTest.getBytes()))));
which caused another error:
programTest.java:11: error: 'void' type not allowed here
        assertEquals(10, program.dateValidation(System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputTest.getBytes()))));
                                                                      ^
1 error


I am not sure if I am even doing the testing correctly, so I was wondering what is the correct way to do this?

the method takes an argument dateValidation(Scanner sc) but when calling, no argument is passed program.dateValidation(). You are not passing the scanner.

Yeah, so I tried passing in the things listed but it also doesnt work, so what should i pass inside to make the test work?

pass scanner Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); assertEquals(10, program.dateValidation(scanner));

Even better, just make the Scanner wrap the ByteArrayInputStream directly, rather than replacing System.in.

Now it says error: cannot find symbol   assertEquals(10, program.dateValidation(sc));   ^   symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)   location: class programTest and
programTest.java:13: error: dateValidation(Scanner) has private access in program   assertEquals(10, program.dateValidation(sc));                                     ^ 2 errors ? So sorry if im doing this wrong ;;

Scanner userInput = new Scanner("10"); ... program.dateValidation(userInput); (the Scanner class has a constructor that accepts a String as source)

or just program.dateValidation(new Scanner(inputTest)); (not closing the Scanner, only good for short tests)
